# Start page from same point when Beamer frame has no title

Tags: beamer, itemize, frame-title

[image]

I am making a presentation using beamer environment in latex. However, one of my slides does not have the frame title (The slide next to slide  no. 17 in this pic). So, what is happening is that the text in slide no. 18 is starting from the place of the frame title above the blue line. However, I want the text in slide no. 18 to start below the blue line. What shall I do to accomplish that?

For the purpose of MWE, and since the template in this pic may  not be available with everyone, so for simplification, I have made another MWE, that does not require any extra template files to run, but has the same problem.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    
\section{Introduction to }
\begin{frame}[t]{\bigskip \Large Introduction } 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Delay is a 
        \item Delay is a 
            \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
                \item Delay is a 
                    \item Delay is a 
                        \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]    
\begin{itemize}
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: use just the `\bigskip` as title for frames that do not have a real title.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    
\section{Introduction to }
\begin{frame}[t]{\bigskip \Large Introduction } 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Delay is a 
        \item Delay is a 
            \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
                \item Delay is a 
                    \item Delay is a 
                        \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]{\bigskip}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a 
    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a    \item Delay is a 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]